# Is it safe to use private key in this code

Tags: web3js, erc-20

I'm trying to create a smart contract and I have a doubt about a line.

```
import privateKeyToAddress from 'ethereum-private-key-to-address'
import Web3 from 'web3';

const address = privateKeyToAddress(Buffer.from(privateKey.substr(2), 'hex')).toString('hex');
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
   chainId: 2020,
   data: data,
   from: address,
   gas: 570331,
   gasPrice: "0x0",
   to: addresses.market,
}, privateKey)
```

is it safe to use my private key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.
It's never safe to put your private keys in any code. Your keys should be in a hardware wallet or a HSM or a Vault.
As soon as you paste write it on a computer or smartphone, assuming your are not on an air gapped computer but you would know it, then your keys are compromised.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but to create a smart contract it's necessary, I think about using another wallet when I'm gonna use this script, is that fine?

Comment: No. Not necessary. Unless you need it to execute without action on your side, the script can trigger a request to your hardware wallet that will require you to approve the smart contract deployment transaction. You can also use the Ethereum object provided by Metamask that will raise a request on your wallet. But always keep your keys in a safe wallet. Code samples with keys directly pasted in them are mistakes, we should stop writing any in our docs. It's advertising a bad way to code.

Comment: To be clear: there are different levels of security, and keeping your private key on a hardware wallet is a lot less important than, say, not putting your private key into a part of a transaction where people can see it.

Comment: If your keys are handled by a hardware wallet, it's impossible to put them anywhere even by accident. So yes hardware security is required if you want to be safe.